# After subscribe save value into array or variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to save the data after http request and subscribing like below but I cant see the data at the first index. It looks like this within the browser. With this.mySet[0] I have not access to this. What it wrong?

> []0: "test"length: 1__proto__: Array(0)

api.service.ts:409

**myComponent.ts**

```
     mySet = [];
     getLageSub()  {

       this.apiService.getLage().subscribe(data => {this.mySet.push(data)});
console.log(this.mySet)<------here is my output but I will need it elsewhere 

      }
```

**myService.ts**

```
getLage()  {
    let url = 'rest/getData-pool';

    try {
      return this.http.post(url, {}, this.getPutHeaders()).map((res) =>res.json())

    } catch (error) {

      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: do you see anything here console.log(this.mySet)?

Comment: [] 0: "test"length: 1__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will help:

mySet : any;Constructor(){this.mySet = [];}

getLageSub() { this.apiService.getLage().subscribe(data => {this.mySet.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))}); console.log(this.mySet)<------here is my output but I will need it elsewhere }

Answer (score 0):

Try this case :

mySet : any;Constructor(){this.mySet = [];}

getLageSub() { this.apiService.getLage().subscribe(data => {this.mySet.push(data)}); console.log(this.mySet)<------here is my output but I will need it elsewhere }

Comment: nope same result []0: "test"length: 1__proto__: Array(0)